# Spool In SQL Developer is creating blank file

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to do a simple spool the query results are shown and also I can see the file is created. However there is no contents in the file.

```
set heading on
set pagesize 10000
set linesize 1500
set long 9999
set feedback off
set termout off
set sqlformat CSV
spool "c:\\temp\\rptinstances.csv"

select * from rptinstances where requestor_uname like '%JPRAKASH%';

/

    spool off
    /
```

I am using SQL Developer version 21.4.2.018

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer? Works as expected for me, in 22.2, and I don't recall seeing anything like that in any older version, but perhaps there were issues at some point.

Comment: I have updated my question with my SQL Developer version

Comment: What does "blank file" mean? **a)** file is absolutely empty, not a single letter in it, or **b)** there's heading line (column names), but no data?

Comment: it is absolutely empty. No contents at all not even the headers it is 0kb.

Comment: in my statement it works with
spool v:\data\test.csv
No quotes, no double backslash